# Select a Textbox using the Subject

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I am wanting to be able to select a Acrobat Text Box or Polygon using the Subject as the selector.

Eg.

I have a Shape with a subject of "Test.Shape.01"
I want to select that shape as a variable then change the fill and border colours.

How would I go about achieving this?

Comment: You need to show your work so far.  What have you tried?

Comment: You're talking about FreeText and Polygon annotations. Correct?

Comment: @Joelgeraci - yes that is correct.

Comment: @Ian I have nothing to show so far as numerous google searches did not help me find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick...

```
this.syncAnnotScan();
var annots = this.getAnnots();
for (var i = 0; i < annots.length; i++) {
    if (annots[i].subject == "Test.Shape.01") {
        annots[i].fillColor = color.red; // for example
        annots[i].strokeColor = color.red;
        break; // if you know there is only one. Remove if there might be more than one.
    }
}
```

The first line will force Acrobat to rescan the document for any annotations that may have been added since the last time it scanned. Then you simply loop through all of the annotations looking for the ones with the subject you need and them modify their properties. You can see a list of named colors here... https://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/index.html#t=Acro12_MasterBook%2FJS_API_AcroJS%2Fcolor_properties.htm

If you're unsure about where to add this script, tell me more about exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: This is amazing, can you use a custom RGB Value?

Comment: Can you also change the Line colour using this?

Comment: Scratch that I didn't read properly, and have managed to get RGB values working. Thanks So much